# cb_indexedsearch_autocomplete not working for typo3 6.2.17

Tags: typo3-6.2.x

I've just installed the plugin cb_indexedsearch_autocomplete for typo3 and included it in the template. But it is not working for typo3 6.2.17? 
 Is there any configurations to be set?

Comment: Have you read the manual? [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/cb_indexedsearch_autocomplete/ExtIndexedSearchAutocomplete/Configuration/((generated))/Index.html)

Comment: Yes, I've read the manual. But it seems not working. I've installed indexed search too. The default settings for cb_indexedsearch_autocomplete was used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue in the code it iterates a configuration value for jquery library

```
jQueryFile = EXT:cb_indexedsearch_autocomplete/res/jquery-latest.pack.js
```

In Plugin if this is set the value will used and if not set it uses the auto-complete file jquery script. What is the relevance of this usage?.

Now I reset the configuration `jQueryFile` and added CDN Library of Jquery to my page. Now its working like charm.... :)

```
page.includeJSFooter {
    file1 = https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js
    file1.external = 1
}

plugin.cb_indexedsearch_autocomplete.jQueryFile >
plugin.cb_indexedsearch_autocomplete.noConflictMethod = 0
```